# MSCRM 2011 Detecting browser of created record

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

Is there a chance to detect browser of a created Case record with Javascript ?
If yes can you please share the sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add custom field on the case,set the field when create case with javascript.On the form onload read the field with javascript, detect the case created by javascript or not.